# The meaning of "'x' is not a function or its return value is not iterable" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8, for-of-loop

I accidentally witnessed that this causes an error in V8 (Chrome, Node.js, etc):

```
for (let val of Symbol()) { /*...*/ }
```

> TypeError: Symbol is not a function or its return value is not iterable

It appears that any other non-iterable value (including a function) causes another error:

```
for (let val of function () { throw 'never called' }) { /*...*/ }
```

> TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable

As [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable) states, the error is specific to Chrome:

> TypeError: 'x' is not a function or its return value is not iterable (Chrome)
>
> ...
>
> The value which is given as the right hand-side of for…of or as argument of a function such as Promise.all or TypedArray.from, is not an iterable object.  An iterable can be a built-in iterable type such as Array, String or Map, a generator result, or an object implementing the iterable protocol.

It seems that none of listed things are expected to accept a function instead of iterable as an argument so it's unclear why the error puts emphasis on function type.

Is there any meaning to this error? Are there circumstances under which `is not a function` remark makes sense in its context?

Comment: To recreate that error message, try `for (let val of (function () {})()) { }` - you're not *calling* the function in your example.

Comment: I suspect it could be a remnant of some proposal that allowed to pass generator functions instead of generators somewhere where iterators only are accepted now. @jonrsharpe Thanks, this triggers the error indeed.

Comment: It's something to do with using functions to construct primitives. JSC behaves similarly. `for (let val of Number(1)) {}` and `for (let val of Boolean(true)) {}` emit the same error. `for (let val of 1) {}` and `for (let val of true) {}` do not.

Comment: [These are](https://github.com/v8/v8/search?q=is+not+a+function+or+its+return+value+is+not+iterable&unscoped_q=is+not+a+function+or+its+return+value+is+not+iterable) the instances of the string in V8. I cannot find the reference to the entry in the string table however.

Comment: `[...Symbol()]`  will throw the same TypeError, moving here to delete my answer and continue discussion

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is meaning to both parts of the error message. In the case you have at hand, the return value of `Symbol()` is not iterable, so that's the second option. As an example for the first option, just take something that's not a function:

```
let NotAFunction = {};  // Or any other object.
for (let val of NotAFunction()) {}
```

gives: `Uncaught TypeError: NotAFunction is not a function or its return value is not iterable`. In this case, clearly, `NotAFunction` is not a function ;-)

I don't know why there aren't two separate error messages for "it's not a function at all" and "it was a function and it's been called, but its return type wasn't iterable". Presumably something in the internal logic to implement `for..of` loops made it prohibitively complicated to have finer-grained error reporting -- so the combined error message simply mentions two possible reasons why the loop didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The for..of operator pass an argument to a variable trough the iterator protocol.

The iterator protocol specifies the needs of **@@iterator** method to work, so, if the function, object or a class doesn't have the Symbol.iterator/Symbol.asyncIterator implemented it will throw this error.

On the first case, the Symbol it's a constant, so it's not iterable. On the second, the value trowed it's a intermediate value, this means that the VM can't do a conversion to a iterable type(arrays, objects, classes or functions with the iterator method), that is, it can't be executed to get a result due to the fact that the for..of is expecting an implementation of the @@iterator method.

The emphasis comes due the fact that iterator is a function that have the @@iterator method. eg:

```js
const someIterator = {};
someIterator[Symbol.iterator] = function(names) {
    return {
        next() {
            this.index = 0;
            yield names[index];
            this.index = this.index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
{[Symbol.iterator]: [Function (anonymous)]}
```

The expected method of an for..of loop is a iterator function. So, the error message will empathize that is expecting a function.

To implement the method, you can do the same thing above, using ES6 classes, or with objects(accessing trough the key), prototype functions, or just a generator.