# Unit test of component wrapped in react-intl throws `TypeError: _react.default.useContext ... return value is not iterable`

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-intl

I know I need to pass the context to the component under test and I've tried a [few](https://medium.com/7shifts-engineering-blog/testing-usecontext-react-hook-with-enzyme-shallow-da062140fc83) [different](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/kentcdodds/react-testing-library-examples?file=/src/__tests__/react-context.js) ways, but I can't seem to make it work. Under this setup, I'm getting this error:

```
    TypeError: _react.default.useContext is not a function or its return value is not iterable

       7 |
       8 | function MyComponent(props) {
    >  9 |   const [locale, setLocale] = React.useContext(LocaleContext);
         |                                     ^
```

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong? Am I better off switching to enzyme or `react-test-renderer`?

**App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";

import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent ";

import "./App.css";

import { LocaleContext } from "./LocaleContext";
const messages = { zh: require("./translations/zh") };

function App() {
  const [locale] = React.useContext(LocaleContext);

  return (
    <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={messages[locale]}>
      <div className="App">
        <MyComponent />
      </div>
    </IntlProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**LocaleContext.js**

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
export const LocaleContext = React.createContext();
export const useLocaleContext = () => useContext(LocaleContext);

export const LocaleContextProvider = props => {
  const [locale, setLocale] = React.useState("en");
  return (
    <LocaleContext.Provider value={[locale, setLocale]}>
      {props.children}
    </LocaleContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**MyComponent.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";

import { LocaleContext } from "../LocaleContext";

import logo from "../logo.svg";

function MyComponent(props) {
  const [locale, setLocale] = React.useContext(LocaleContext);
  const nextLocale = locale === "en" ? "zh" : "en";

  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h1>
        <FormattedMessage id="title" defaultMessage="Hello World!" />
      </h1>
      <h2>
        <FormattedMessage id="subtitle" defaultMessage="Welcome to our app" />
      </h2>
      <button onClick={() => setLocale(nextLocale)}>
        Change language to {nextLocale}
      </button>
    </header>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

**MyComponent.test.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

import * as LocaleContext from "../LocaleContext";
import MyComponentfrom "./MyComponent";

test("renders `hello world` heading", () => {
  const contextValues = { title: "Hey There" };
  jest
    .spyOn(LocaleContext, "useLocaleContext")
    .mockImplementation(() => contextValues);

  const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent/>);
  const helloWorldText = getByText(/hello world/i);
  expect(helloWorldText).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-intl": "^4.6.9",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Consider removing error message from the title because it was truncated to the point it becomes misleading. The most important part is `its return value is not iterable`. useContext doesn't return an array, this causes the error. And it doesn't return an array because no value for the context was provided. It needs LocaleContextProvider, as the answer suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Fact is, I assumed I had set something up wrong and it genuinely wasn't a function. I'll fix the title for others' benefit.

Comment: Yes, the error is ambiguous, I addressed it some time ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772822/the-meaning-of-x-is-not-a-function-or-its-return-value-is-not-iterable-error . The error would be the same if useContext was indeed not a function, but since it's not possible for React 16.13 or higher, this can be ruled out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to study the [wrapper api](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#wrapper), and setup for a [custom render](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render), but the gist is you create a test wrapper that provides the context provider for testing.

For example, I use react-intl so for testing I have a test utility `intlWrapper`

```
import React from 'react';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';

export const intlWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <IntlProvider locale="en">{children}</IntlProvider>
);
```

And to test a component it is used as such

```
const {/* query selectors */} = render(
  <ComponentUsingIntl />,
  { wrapper: intlWrapper },
);
```

To suit your needs I think you should create a wrapper for your `LocaleContextProvider`

```
import { LocaleContextProvider } from '../LocaleContext';

export const contextWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <LocaleContextProvider>{children}</LocaleContextProvider>
);
```

You can now import your test contextWrapper and use

```
const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent/>, { wrapper: contextWrapper });
```

Answer (score 3):

[drew-reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) gets credit for the answer, but I wanted to follow up the code I used, since it didn't end up using `LocaleContext` in the wrapper.

This also involved [installing an extra dependency](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/1401#issuecomment-519590190) to compile with ICU.

`npm i --save-dev full-icu`

**LocaleContext.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";

const messages = { zh: require("./translations/zh") };

export const LocaleContext = React.createContext();
export const useLocaleContext = () => useContext(LocaleContext);

export const LocaleContextProvider = props => {
  const [locale, setLocale] = React.useState("en");
  return (
    <LocaleContext.Provider value={[locale, setLocale]}>
      {props.children}
    </LocaleContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const intlEnWrapper = {
  wrapper: ({ children }) => <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={messages.en}>{children}</IntlProvider>
};
export const intlZhWrapper = {
  wrapper: ({ children }) => <IntlProvider locale="zh" messages={messages.zh}>{children}</IntlProvider>
};
```

**MyComponent.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

import { intlEnWrapper, intlZhWrapper } from "../../LocaleContext";
import MyComponentfrom "./index";

describe("For en locale", () => {
  test("renders `Title Text` heading", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent/>, intlEnWrapper);
    const titleText = getByText(/title text/i);
    expect(titleText).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

describe("For zh locale", () => {
  test("renders `Title Text` heading", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent />, intlZhWrapper);
    const titleText = getByText(/標題文字/i);
    expect(titleText).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ICU_DATA=node_modules/full-icu react-scripts test"
  }
}
```

Comment: Node 13+ now comes with the full ICU btw