# "TypeError: react.useContext is not a function" when mocking context Providers with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library, react-context

I am trying to determine how best to mock Providers when Jest testing with React Context.  The most promising lead I've found is RTL, which provides the following example in their docs: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-context

I have been experimenting with multiple structures, but even when I follow their example closely I get the above error.

Here I am following their example almost exactly when testing my Dialog component:

Jest Test

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { DialogContext, defaultState } from '../../../../store/contexts/dialogContext';

const customRender = (ui, { providerProps, ...renderOptions }) => {
  return render(
    <DialogContext.Provider {...providerProps}>{ui}</DialogContext.Provider>,
    renderOptions
  );
};

it('Dialog should work', async () => {
  const providerProps = {
    dialogType: 'CANCEL',
    ...defaultState,
  };
  const { container } = customRender(<Dialog />, { providerProps });
  const results = await axe(container);

  expect(results).toHaveNoViolations();
});
```

Dialog Component

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { DialogContext } from '../../../store/contexts/dialogContext';

export default function Dialog() {
  const [dialogState, dialogDispatch] = useContext(DialogContext);

  //logic

 return (
  <div id='dialog'/>
  );
}
```

This is a simplified version of my Dialog Component, but I receive the following error as soon as it invokes useContext() on line 2.

```
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: (0 , _react.useContext) is not a function or its return value is not iterable]
```

As 'React' is in scope in the relevant files, and I'm following the RTL example closely, I'm stumped.  Solutions or recommendations for other ways to mock Providers welcome.

**EDIT:** Adding the dialogContext file for clarity.  The component and the context work fine when not in the Jest flow.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { dialogReducer } from '../reducers/dialogReducer';

export const DialogContext = createContext({});
const { Provider } = DialogContext;

export const defaultState = {
  //state object
}

export const DialogProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, reducer] = useReducer(dialogReducer, defaultState);

  return <Provider value={[state, reducer]}>{children}</Provider>
}
```

and when DialogContext is logged from within the Dialog component (the line before), it looks as expected:

```
{ '$$typeof': Symbol(react.context),
        _calculateChangedBits: null,
        _currentValue: undefined,
        _currentValue2: {},
        _threadCount: 0,
        Provider: { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.provider), _context: [Circular] },
        Consumer:
         { '$$typeof': Symbol(react.context),
           _context: [Circular],
           _calculateChangedBits: null },
        _currentRenderer: {},
        _currentRenderer2: null }
```

Comment: Whether `{ useContext }` works is very specific to your Jest config, the error is ambiguous, but it's more likely that useContext doesn't return an array while it's assumed by destructuring. Nothing in the code you posted suggests that the context was provided with array value.

Comment: Can you give me more information on the Jest config?  We have a generic Jest set up with CRA but I can change or override that.  If it's not obvious, the component and Context works when not in this mocked flow, but I will add the Context file for clarity.

Comment: If you use CRA then there should be no problem with Jest config, at least in this respect. Thanks. It's the difference between test and prodiction code that causes a problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error [is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772822/the-meaning-of-x-is-not-a-function-or-its-return-value-is-not-iterable-error) and can really occur when `useContext` is undefined and when `useContext` is a function but doesn't return an iterable (array).

The first situation can happen if Jest was incorrectly configured and `react` package is imported as CommonJS module that is translated to ES module `default` import via module interop.

The second situation is the most simple explanation for the error. Context provider wasn't provided with array value so `useContext` doesn't return an array. Unless `defaultState` object contains `value` pro...perty with array value, `...defaultState` spread will result in wrong provider value.

Provider value should be provided in tests the same way it was in the app:

```
<Provider value={[state, reducer]}>...
```

If the intention is to not use `dialogReducer` in the test, a spy can be provided instead:

```
<DialogContext.Provider value={[defaultState, mockedDispach]}>...
```

Otherwise `DialogProvider` can be used instead of `DialogContext.Provider` because it already provides expected provider value.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you!  When I pass in the original reducer to the mocked Provider `<DialogContext.Provider value={[testState, dialogReducer]}>{ui}</DialogContext.Provider>` and fixed the syntax when I passed in state to the customRender `customRender(<Dialog />, { testState })`, it works great ---- Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what and where to do in the first situation?

Comment: @ShashankAC Usually Jest and Babel/Typescript configs need to be fixed. Can't say more precisely, this depends on your case. Sticking to the configs from a template instead of writing it from scratch may help. If this is the case for you, consider asking a new question that reflects it

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.mock('react', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react'),
    useContext: jest.fn(),
}))
```

Add this line before configuring the adapter.

```
configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```