# How to solve this React Type Error on Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMr84.png)

```
    const isSignUp = false;
    const handleChange = () => {};
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);

    const handlePassword = () =>
        setShowPassword((prevShowPassword) => !prevShowPassword);
```

I was implementing the password show/hide feature using usestate and I don't understand why I get this error.
Do help how to solve it?

Comment: Please provide code snippet in the question.

Comment: These should ideally be two different messages. Take a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61772822/the-meaning-of-x-is-not-a-function-or-its-return-value-is-not-iterable-error

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

There was error when I had this :

```
import useState from "react";
```

It got solved when I changed it to this :

```
import { useState } from "react";
```